# GUI Freezes while downloading PyQt5 and Pytube

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pytube

I have made a Desktop Application using Python and used PyQt5 and Pytube which could download video from youtube. When download is in Progress, I want to show user an animation. In Fact I did it, but when the file is getting downloaded the PyQt window seems like freezing and everything just gets paused until the download is complete. So, Does anyone know why is this happening? How do I fix it?

Here's the code snippet:

```
def download_created(self, qual): # Used in 'selection' method
    selected_stream = yt.streams.get_by_resolution(qual)
    self.progress_func()
    try:
        self.download_btn.setCurrentIndex(-1)
        selected_stream.download(self.askLocation() + "/")
    except:
        pass
    
# This gets the quality that the user chooses
def selection(self):
    global quality
    quality = self.download_btn.currentText()
    try:
        self.download_created(quality) # Calls a method called 'download'
    except:
        self.start_anime()
# Fetching the details about the Link from Youtube
def download_youtube(self):
    global check
    if check != self.get_input():
        check = self.get_input()
        self.download_btn.clear()
        enter_url = self.get_input()
        try:
            global yt
            yt = pytube.YouTube(
                enter_url,
                on_progress_callback = on_progress, 
                on_complete_callback = self.complete_func)
            
            self.start_anime()
        except:
            self.input_error()
        VIDEO_TITLE = (yt.title)
        global VIDEO_ID
        VIDEO_ID = (yt.video_id)
        videos = yt.streams.filter(mime_type="video/mp4", progressive="True")

        # Display all the available qualities
        for i in videos:
            self.download_btn.addItem(i.resolution)
        self.download_btn.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.selection)
```

Comment: pytube doesn't seem to provide asynchronous functions, meaning that all its functions are *blocking* (so, the UI is "blocked" and unresponsive until they return). The only way then is to use a QThread that will manage the download process, so I suggest you to do some research on the subject, as there are literally hundreds of posts about it.

Comment: Thank You... Can you suggest me some best source to study about it?

Answer (score 2):

You have to execute the time consuming tasks in another thread, for example in your case the task of getting the streams and downloading.

```py
import sys
import threading
from functools import cached_property

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

import pytube


class QPyTube(QtCore.QObject):
    initialized = QtCore.pyqtSignal(bool, str)
    download_started = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    download_progress_changed = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    download_finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, url):
        super().__init__()
        self._url = url
        self._yt = None
        self._mutex = threading.Lock()

        threading.Thread(target=self._init, daemon=True).start()

    @property
    def url(self):
        return self._url

    @cached_property
    def resolutions(self):
        return list()

    def _init(self):
        with self._mutex:
            self.resolutions.clear()
        try:
            self._yt = pytube.YouTube(
                self.url,
                on_progress_callback=self._on_progress,
                on_complete_callback=self._on_complete,
            )
            streams = self._yt.streams.filter(mime_type="video/mp4", progressive="True")
        except Exception as e:
            self.initialized.emit(False, str(e))
            return
        with self._mutex:
            self.resolutions = [stream.resolution for stream in streams]
        self.initialized.emit(True, "")

    def download(self, resolution, directory):
        threading.Thread(
            target=self._download, args=(resolution, directory), daemon=True
        ).start()

    def _download(self, resolution, directory):
        stream = self._yt.streams.get_by_resolution(resolution)
        self.download_started.emit()
        stream.download(directory)

    def _on_progress(self, stream, chunk, bytes_remaining):
        self.download_progress_changed.emit(
            100 * (stream.filesize - bytes_remaining) // stream.filesize
        )

    def _on_complete(self, stream, filepath):
        self.download_finished.emit()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.le_url = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("http://youtube.com/watch?v=2lAe1cqCOXo")
        self.lbl_error = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.btn_search = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Search")
        self.cmb_resolutions = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.le_directory = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("")
        self.btn_download = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Download")
        self.pgb_download = QtWidgets.QProgressBar()

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        lay = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(central_widget)
        lay.addWidget(self.le_url, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.btn_search, 0, 1)
        lay.addWidget(self.cmb_resolutions, 1, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.le_directory, 1, 1)
        lay.addWidget(self.btn_download, 1, 2)
        lay.addWidget(self.pgb_download, 2, 0, 1, 3)

        self.btn_download.setEnabled(False)

        self._qpytube = None

        self.btn_search.clicked.connect(self.handle_search_clicked)
        self.btn_download.clicked.connect(self.handle_download_clicked)

    def handle_search_clicked(self):
        self.cmb_resolutions.clear()
        self.btn_search.setEnabled(False)
        self.btn_download.setEnabled(False)
        self.lbl_error.clear()
        self._qpytube = QPyTube(self.le_url.text())
        self._qpytube.initialized.connect(self.handle_initialized)
        self._qpytube.download_progress_changed.connect(self.pgb_download.setValue)
        self._qpytube.download_started.connect(self.handle_download_started)
        self._qpytube.download_finished.connect(self.handle_download_finished)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(bool, str)
    def handle_initialized(self, status, error=""):
        if status:
            self.cmb_resolutions.addItems(self._qpytube.resolutions)
            self.btn_download.setEnabled(True)
        else:
            self.lbl_error.setText(error)
        self.btn_search.setEnabled(True)

    def handle_download_clicked(self):
        self._qpytube.download(
            self.cmb_resolutions.currentText(), self.le_directory.text()
        )
        self.btn_search.setEnabled(False)
        self.btn_download.setEnabled(False)
        self.le_directory.setEnabled(False)

    def handle_download_started(self):
        self.lbl_error.clear()
        print("started")

    def handle_download_finished(self):
        self.pgb_download.setValue(100)
        self.btn_search.setEnabled(True)
        self.btn_download.setEnabled(True)
        self.le_directory.setEnabled(True)
        print("finished")


def main(args):
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(args)

    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()

    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: I like your answer and I've not worked with threads much. So can we please edit my code directly in github Repo?? It'll be nice If you could help me out.
https://github.com/hsmaharaj1/youvloader

Comment: I'm not asking you to work on my project. I've already made one. If you don't mind help me solving this specific problem in my project. That's all. And Can you please tell me How do I study about this QThreads so that I can implement this ?

Comment: @HimanshuSekharMaharaj As I already told you: I only help to solve specific problems in SO. Precisely because SO limits the extension of the problems is the main reason that I actively participate here, I do not want to invest my time in helping more extensive problems since they are not of interest to me. Bye, read [ask] and review the [tour]. So please do not ask the community to implement the answers in your projects since that is not the logic of the site, we are not tutors or similar.

Comment: Okay.. Thank you

Comment: Hey I'm trying to make a thread with _thread and threading module why is it not working?

Comment: @HimanshuSekharMaharaj Why do you want to use _thread? You should not use _thread as it is part of the private API

Comment: okay.. I've also tried using concurrent.future, ThreadPoolExecutor But sill showing the error.

Comment: @HimanshuSekharMaharaj Why do you want to change my code? As I already pointed out: I am only responsible for my code, if you want to modify it, it is your responsibility. I would accept to use other classes if my code had a flaw but as you already pointed it out to me: my code works. Your problem is that you don't know how to integrate it into your project

Comment: I apologize for that. It's because your code is not working in my system. As I'm using python 3.7, it's showing NameError:: and cached_property can't be imported. That's why I was trying to modify it. Do you know why I'm getting the error from your code also?

Comment: How difficult was it to point that out to me? The solution is to install `backports.cached-property` (`python -m pip install backports.cached-property`) and change `from functools import cached_property` to `from backports.cached_property import cached_property`

Comment: Thank you a lot. I hope it works this time

Comment: @HimanshuSekharMaharaj 1) You should have indicated the version of each element of your environment because if you do not indicate it we will assume that the latest stable version is being used, in this case python 3.9.5. In your case, cached_property was implemented in python 3.8 that's why you have this problem, 2) Every time the solution code throws an error you must point it out in order to correct it or adapt it to your environment.

Comment: again this is showing this error AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'clear'

Comment: @HimanshuSekharMaharaj In which line of code does this error generate you? Displays the complete error message.

Comment: Ya I'm doing as u said. Just copied ur code and pasted in another file, replaced to backports.chached_property but it's generating the same error

Comment: Dude Can't you make the same using QThreadPool ?? What's the problem with it?

Comment: @eyllanesc I have used your code and its fantastic, but all of a sudden, it made my program so slow, like the download only starts after a while (when previously that didn't happen), and the qpytube thread only initializes after some seconds. I must also add that I have a qt web engine view that shows the youtube video, i don't know if that's the problem but I'm getting errors like these: "ERROR:database.cc(1632)] Quota sqlite error 1, errno 33: cannot start a transaction within a transaction, sql:" or "ERROR:leveldb_factory.cc(91)] Failed to open LevelDB database from C", any help is good, ty