# Problem with the app created using PyQt5 Designer and PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I developed an Youtube video downloader app using PyQt5.. It works fine when I run it with my interpreter and I'm getting the expected output.. But after converting it into an executable file using pyinstaller, when I run the exe file, it enters the application and comes out after I give some input..I think there is an error with shifting between windows but I dont know where I specifically made the error...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GUI Freezes while downloading PyQt5 and Pytube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67516353/gui-freezes-while-downloading-pyqt5-and-pytube)

Comment: The one you have mentioned is not my problem... After converting it into a exe file using pyinstaller, when I open that file, it opens normally but after entering the url, when I press enter, it has to switch to the next screen but it comes out of the app... This code works fine when I run it in my interpreter as a py file but after converting into exe, something goes wrong

Comment: Have you used pyinstaller's --add-data argument to bundle ffmpeg with your executable? It's possible that it's trying to access ffmpeg and not finding it so it throws and error and crashes.

Comment: No, I didn't.. Can you explain the process of bundling ffmpeg and adding it to pyinstaller in detail

Comment: Okay.. I just checked how to add data to our executables and tried it, I checked the spec file and it show that I have included ffmpeg.exe but still the error persists...

Comment: @TharunR add some debugging `print()` around the program and also run it in a command prompt to see if outputs any useful traceback. If you still have no clue, you can only try to slowly reduce the program until you reach a situation that does *not* create the issue. Besides, you should *not* add a QDialog (nor a QMainWindow) to a QStackedWidget.

Comment: @musicamante
So, through which way, we can create multi screen application

Comment: @TharunR QMainWindow and QDialog are intended to be used as standalone windows only. Just subclass from QWidget. Note that you also have to create new UI files (use select "Widget" in the new form dialog of Designer), you can then drag and drop the current contents of the windows you're using to the new one if you don't want to do them again from scrach.

Comment: I will try and remind you of what results I get..

Comment: Still the same problem persists..

Comment: First of all, I wanna thank all who involved in my path of solving the problem.. I just found the error.. I imported the requests module which does certificate verification.. In that I had some error.. After setting verify = False in the get() function of requests module, the error rectified.. Once again, thanks for the immediate response and support..